# Using FileReadFields with Wonderware

Tags: user-interface, wonderware

I suppose this is a long shot considering how few Wonderware questions I've seen on here, but anyway...

The FileReadFields function in Wonderware is supposed to parse a CSV file into memory tags.  There are no debug messages when stuff doesn't work in Wonderware (not my choice of HMI software, that's for sure), so I have no idea why this isn't working:

```
FileReadFields("C:\NASA\Sample.csv", 0, Profile_Setup_Name, 1);
```

Everything is cased correctly and the file is not in-use.  I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Wonderware does have a (sometimes cryptic) debugging tool called WWLogger. Newer versions of Wonderware Intouch house this logger under an app called "System Management Console" under "Log Viewer" in the System Console Tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileReadFields function is used to read several values from a CSV file into a series of tagnames. You can not store those values into just one tag. Because a CSV file can contain several values per line, you need more than one tagname to receive all the values. Those tagnames must end in a number (i.e. MyTag1, MyTag2, MyTag3, ...). Additionally, the tagname must be enclosed with double quotes

This is a correct example:

FileReadFields("C:\NASA\Sample.csv", 0, "MyTag1", 1);

Where MyTag1 is the first tagname. You have to create MyTag1, MyTag2, MyTag3....

Answer (score -1):

I wrote FileReadFields.  I think it works fine.